# BizTalk 2009 Message error - The following procedure call failed

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009

Very frequently the following error is getting logged into Application event logs on my BizTalk 2009 VM. But this error is inconsistent. Any clues?

> The following stored procedure call failed: " { call [dbo].[bts_UpdateMsgbox_BizTalkServerApplication]( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}". SQL Server returned error string: "Warning: The join order has been enforced because a local join hint is used.;Warning: The join order has been enforced because a local join hint is used.;Duplicate key was ignored.".

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen that error myself, but it sounds like someone messed with the BizTalkMsgBox DB. Have your DBAs by any chance changed any of the sql server settings, or maybe messed with the BizTalkMsgBox indices? (like rebuild them?)

Comment: Nothing as such happened; Its on a VM. Even the SQL server is installed with all the deafult / biztalk dependent settings.

Comment: We are getting the same symptoms.  Pity that there is no solution to this.

Comment: Seeing the same error with BizTalk 2013r2 on Sql Server 2012r2

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work-around this by disabling tracking on the send port that was sending my message